# Regex that accepts only three specific letters a hyphen and 6 digit number

Tags: php

Can someone help with this code?

This code is for server validation

It must start with SEQ or ABC or MHT followed by '-' than 6 or 9 and followed by any digits

example SEQ-900000

```
$value = $data['firstname'];
// ^$ = anchors, [a-zA-Z ] = letters/spaces, {1,30} = 1-30 characters
$format = "/^[a-zA-Z ]{1,30}$/";
// If value does NOT match the format then it is invalid
if (!preg_match($format, $value)) {
    $feedback['firstname'] = 'Server feedback: Only 1-30 letters/spaces are permitted';
    $valid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do,

```
$value = $data['firstname'];
$format = '/^(SEQ|ABC|MHT)\-([69]([0-9]{5}))$/D';
// If value does NOT match the format then it is invalid
if (preg_match($format, $value) !== 1) {
    $feedback['firstname'] = 'Server feedback: Only 1-30 letters/spaces are permitted';
    $valid = false;
}
```

*note that not only the `$format`, but the `preg_match` line has been changed aswell.*

Comment: 6 digit number?

Comment: He mentioned a variable amount of digits, and a literal `6` or `9` as first number after the dash; unless i've misunderstood that is. Oh i see what you mean now, its in the title but not in the question. Updated it to 6 digits.

Comment: Yes, it's great